# Firestore error when paginating with document snapshot and `where` clause

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

```py
def getPayments ():
    col = firestoreClient.collection('payments')
    query = col.where('paymentId', '==', None).limit(10).order_by('__name__')

    lastDoc = None
    for doc in query.stream():
        lastDoc = doc

    query = col.where('paymentId', '==', None).limit(10).order_by('__name__').start_after(lastDoc)

    lastDoc = None
    for doc in query.stream(): # Errors here
        lastDoc = doc
```

On the 2nd query.stream(), i get this error `google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 order by clause cannot contain more fields after the key`.

I followed the [pagination documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor), but added a `where` clause which broke it. If I remove the `where` clauses it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried to define the second query only as `query = query.start_after(lastDoc)`. Does it make any difference?